# bootstrap navbar active element options?

Tags: php, css, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

Is there anyway in bootstrap 4 to highlight the active element.

Currently Home is the active element, but it isn't that bold enough.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<li class="nav navbar-nav ">
    <a class="nav-link {{ Request::is('/') ? "active" : "" }}" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

just style the `.nav-link.active` simply

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: red;
}
```